# Multi-threading: Program create 10 threads and calls method print thread make sure the output of this method do not interrupt each other

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

Above prog is working by calling both `wait()` and  `join()`. Can you tell me which method I should use. Or is there a better way to write  this program .Thanks in advance :)
For `thread.wait()` I create a syncronized block before calling `t.start()`.

```
public class DisplayThread {

    public synchronized void printThread(int threadNumber){
        System.out.println("I am thread number: " + threadNumber);

    }
}


public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    DisplayThread d;
    int num;

    Thread1(DisplayThread d, int num) {
        this.d = d;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void run() {
        d.printThread(num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DisplayThread d = new DisplayThread();
        Thread[] t = new Thread[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            t[i] = new Thread1(d, i);
            t[i].start();
            try {
                t[i].join();  **//t[i].wait(1000) also works fine**
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This looks fine to me if you're just trying to print the thread ID.

Comment: One more question. If I use wait() from where do i call notify() and  how?

Comment: `Thread#wait` and `Thread#notify` should not be used in this example.

Comment: Check out my answer if you're looking to have each `Thread` run concurrently instead of running sequentially as your program currently does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to have the 10 `Thread`s execute concurrently, you'll need to move the `Thread#join` call outside of the initial loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    t[i] = new Thread1(d, i);
    t[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    try {
        t[i].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Other than that, everything looks fine to me!

Comment: @Vidz You're welcome!  If you problem is solved, feel free to upvote/accept the answer by clicking on the green tick to the left of the post.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell me which method I should use?

You need to use `join()` method only by which you are telling the `main` thread not to start (i.e., the line `t[i].start()`) the next threads in the iteration. If you don't use join(), the `main` thread also run parallelly and starts the other threads.

Also, `wait()` and `notify()` are meant to solve a different problem i.e., producer/consumer problem, I suggest you look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) to understand how this concept works.